# Kotlin: Can we use @Subscribe of EventBus (GreenRobot) in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, greenrobot-eventbus

My onEvent in a fragment as below, capturing the authentication of the activity, in my Kotlin function. However, I can't get that onEvent triggered.

```
@Subscribe
fun onEvent(event: AuthenticationEvent) {
    if (event.isAuthenticated) {
        startFragment(signInFragment, SignInFragment.TAG)
    } else {
        startFragment(signOutFragment, SignOutFragment.TAG)
    }
}
```

In my build.gradle file, I have add this

```
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
```

Is there anything I need to do to get this trigger?

Comment: How do you post your Event? Have your registered eventbus in your activity? Please add more informatiion.

Comment: https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/issues/286

Comment: I have register onResume, and unregister onPause. The same post of event could be capture on another class in Java.

Comment: Try to register in onStart and unregister in onStop. Maybe your event is fired before you register to eventbus.

Comment: Can I know how you solve the issue. I am facing a similar problem.

Comment: onEvent() function should be public

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use annotation processors with Kotlin, you need to use the [Kotlin Annotation Processor tool (kapt)](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html).

Add this to your `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

[According to GreenRobot](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/issues/286) (and confirmed by my testing), this is all you need to get `@Subscribe`.

Comment: Since the EventBus 3.1.1, we don't need to add this anymore. Anyway, this is the correct workaround.

Answer (score 4):

1. Make sure your event handler function with `@Subscribe` annotation is **public**
2. In the `build.gradle` file add the code:

   ```
   apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

   implementation "org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0"
   kapt 'org.greenrobot:eventbus-annotation-processor:3.0.1'
   ```
3. If you want to use `Subscriber Index`, you add the code to `build.gradle` too:

   `kapt {
       arguments {
           arg('eventBusIndex', 'your-package.MyEventBusIndex')
       }
   }`

Answer (score 0):

You could use Square's [Otto](https://github.com/square/otto), which works the same way and works perfectly with Kotlin. Although, be careful as EventBuses are prone to overcomplicate Android code, and that's why they've deprecated the framework in favor of Rx.

Comment: This project is deprecated in favor of RxJava and RxAndroid. These projects permit the same event-driven programming model as Otto, but they’re more capable and offer better control of threading.

If you’re looking for guidance on migrating from Otto to Rx, this post is a good start. https://blog.kaush.co/2014/12/24/implementing-an-event-bus-with-rxjava-rxbus/